# How to add breaks in apex:datatable

Tags: visualforce, datatable, style

I have an `apex:datatable` that lists opportunityLineItems.  I want to render the columns based on the value of the lineitem field `Product_Type__c` and then add a break in between each group.  I am able to get the render to work, but cannot figure out how to add a break in between.  (I've tried using `<br/>`, tried multiple data tables wrapped in outputpanels, I even tried using repeat instead, but that was even more limited).

Here are a couple examples of what I'm trying (but not getting the result I need):

FIRST ATTEMPT:

```
 <apex:dataTable value="{!Opportunity.opportunityLineItems}" rendered="{!Opportunity.Mandatory__c}" var="OP" width="98.7%">
      <apex:column rendered="{!OP.Product_Type__c = 'Mandatory'}" value="{!OP.ProductCode}" styleClass="tbl_bdr tal" style="width:10%;"></apex:column>
  </apex:dataTable>    

 <apex:dataTable value="{!Opportunity.opportunityLineItems}" rendered="{!Opportunity.Base__c}" var="OP" width="98.7%">
     <apex:column rendered="{!OP.Product_Type__c = 'Base'}" value="{!OP.ProductCode}" styleClass="tbl_bdr tal" style="width:10%;"></apex:column>
  </apex:dataTable>
```

SECOND ATTEMPT:

```
 <apex:dataTable value="{!Opportunity.opportunityLineItems}" rendered="{!Opportunity.Mandatory__c}" var="OP" width="98.7%">
     <apex:column rendered="{!OP.Product_Type__c = 'Mandatory'}" value="{!OP.ProductCode}" styleClass="tbl_bdr tal" style="width:10%;"></apex:column>
     <br/>
     <apex:column rendered="{!OP.Product_Type__c = 'Base'}" value="{!OP.ProductCode}" styleClass="tbl_bdr tal" style="width:10%;"></apex:column>
  </apex:dataTable>
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that. `<apex:column>`'s are turned into parts of a `<table>` and tables don't allow elements to fit in between columns. You should look into using CSS to add a space or border between the generated table elements.

Comment: You have to add empty rows.

Comment: You'd have to process the data in JavaScript, or use a custom controller. You can't do this in markup.

Comment: How do I add empty rows?